# Can't add items from a List of Students to a ListBox from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an issue with displaying items from a list of students onto a ListBox on my Window.
I want my ListBox to be able to display all the students names upon a Button click.

My problem is that the method to display the items is in a different class and does not recognize the ListBox name.

Here is my code in `MainWindow.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UniRecords
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //allows for communication to university class
        private University myUniversity = new University();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Add to List Button
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //adding one student 
            Student peter = new Student();
            peter.Name = "Peter";
            peter.Address = "3 braeburn Drive";
            peter.Matriculation = 43425321;

            //add student through 3 different text boxes
            Student newStudent = new Student(txtName.Text, txtAddress.Text, Convert.ToInt32(this.txtMatriculation.Text));

            //communicates with addStudent Method in University class
            myUniversity.addStudent(newStudent);
        }

        //Display in list box button
        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //communicates with showClassList method in university class
            myUniversity.showClassList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Code in University Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace UniRecords
{
    class University
    {
        //Initiating list to store students
        private List<Student> student = new List<Student>();

        public void addStudent(Student newStudent)
        {
            //adding student to list
            student.Add(newStudent);
        }

        public void showClassList() //Links to Student class
        {
            foreach (Student c in student)
            {
                //listStudent is the name of the listbox
                //c.showList communicates with student class and return value for students name
                //THIS IS WHERE I GET LOST
                listStudent.Items.Add(c.showList());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code in Student Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace UniRecords
{
    class Student
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private string dob;
        private int matricNo;

        public Student() { }

        //constructor to take in 3 arguments
        public Student(string studentName, string studentAddress, int studentMatricNo)
        {
           name = studentName;
           address = studentAddress;
           matricNo = studentMatricNo;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return address;
            }
            set
            {
                address = value;
            }
        }

        public int Matriculation
        {
            get
            {
                return matricNo;
            }
            set
            {
                matricNo = value;
            }
        }

        public string showList()
        {
            return name + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to test the list using `MessageBox.Show()` so i know the information is there, i just cant seem to be able to display it to my ListBox.

Thank you anyone who can help!

Comment: Seperate your `View` from your `Controller` ([MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make your list of student public and populate the listbox in the `MainWindow` class like below.

***Warning Untested Code***

**In University Class**

```
    public List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
```

**In MainWindow Class**

```
    // Moved from University Class
    private void showClassList() //Links to Student class
    {
        foreach (Student c in myUniversity.student)
        {
            //listStudent is the name of the listbox
            //c.showList communicates with student class and return value for students name
            listStudent.Items.Add(c.showList());
        }
    }
    //Display in list box button
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //communicates with showClassList method in university class
        showClassList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the task of the `University` class to deal with list boxes. You could declare it simply as:

```
class University
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; } = new List<Student>();
}
```

If you override the `ToString` method of the student, you can add the students directly to the list box. The list box uses `ToString` automatically to display items. This allows you to add `Student` objects to the list box, instead of strings.

```
class Student
{
    public Student(string studentName, string studentAddress, int studentMatricNo)
    {
        Name = studentName;
        Address = studentAddress;
        Matriculation = studentMatricNo;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Matriculation { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Now you can add students with

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student newStudent = new Student(txtName.Text, txtAddress.Text, Convert.ToInt32(this.txtMatriculation.Text));
    myUniversity.Students.Add(newStudent);
}
```

and you can display the list with

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listStudent.Items.Clear();
    listStudent.Items.AddRange(myUniversity.Students.ToArray());
}
```

---

Note that I used auto-implemented properties. They create and handle their backing field automatically. For instance

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

does exactly the same as

```
private string name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

however, the backing field is hidden and not accessible directly.